# JFileChooser filename

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a problem with `JFileChooser`. I am embedding it in a custom dialog and the custom dialog has its own OK and Cancel buttons and the dialog is not changeable.

I am therefore setting `JFileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown` to `false` which hides the buttons. On clicking the custom dialog's OK button I call `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile` to get the selected file.

But there is a problem. If I choose a directory or file with the files list or click the special buttons like Home or Desktop then that all works. So I select a file in the chooser (which updates the file name field with the file's name).

BUT now if I change the file's name by clicking in the file name textfield and edit the filename then when I subsequently call `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile` I get the name of the original file, not an amended File object reflecting the new filename that I typed.

So I suspect that clicking the `JFileChooser`'s Approve button causes the file object returned to be updated. My suspicions are also based on the fact that if I listen for a PropertyChangeEvent of type `SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY` then this is only called when using the picker or special buttons, not when the textfield end editing occurs.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem? I also tried `JFileChooser.approveSelection` but that had no apparent effect.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Did you try to set the DialogType to `SAVE_DIALOG`? I think that it will allow to take into account a modified file name.

Comment: Changing the dialog type does not seem to change this. However, pressing the "Approve"/"Open"/"Save" button indeed modifies the returned file. One way to "fix" this could be to retrieve the FileChooserUI associated with your JFileChooser and either try to retrieve the "Approve" button and use "doClick()" on it (before retrieving the selected file) or to directly ask for the fileName entered in the textfield (using getFileName() which is available on `BasicFileChooserUI`). Maybe somebody will have a better solution for that.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, Yes I had the same thought if I can doClick(). Even looked at the FileChooserUI but missed it was abstract and subclassed doh!! However BasicFileChooserUI.getApproveButton() returns null. But getFileName does return the updated value so its easy to getSelectedFile and replace the filename portion. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JohnSmith He meant call [`JFileChooser.getUI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getUI%28%29) to get the chooser's actual `FileChooserUI`. Or is this what you actually did?